# Does client making asmx call use ephemeral port?

Tags: sockets, proxy, client, asmx, port

I have a client which makes asmx call to a server. I have a question regarding the port that need to be open at the client to communicate with the server.

In our scenario, we intend to keep all ports closed in the client (its inside the firewall). As per my understanding when client makes a asmx call to the server, it opens an ephemeral port at the client and the server will response back at this port.

So, do I need to open these port at the client?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this by setting the [BindIPEndPointDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.bindipendpointdelegate.aspx) of the [ServicePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.aspx) which is being used in the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) being used for the connection.

See [Ways to Customize your ASMX Client Proxy](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/ways-to-customize-your-asmx-client-proxy/) for details of customizing the `HttpWebRequest`.